# Having difficulty passing command line arguments to robocopy

Tags: python, html, subprocess, batch-processing

I'm very new to Python but would love to use it for writing batch processes.  Trying to execute the code below and everything works except the exclude directory option.  Does anyone knowhow I can fix this?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["robocopy",r"c:\rob",r"c:\rob1", "/nocopy", r'/xd gp'])


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, February 24, 2017 6:47:37 PM
   Source - c:\fred\
     Dest - c:\fred1\

    Files :
  Options : /NOCOPY /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "/xd gp"

       Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?



****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["robocopy",r"c:\rob",r"c:\rob1", "/nocopy", r'/xd', 'gp'])
```

As in separate the option from the value of the option because those should be separate arguments to robocopy but it's getting them as a single parameter

> '/xd gp'